# Can I send a Image to whatsApp using html hyperlink / a tag?

Tags: javascript, html

we can send text using html a tag with the following code

`<a href="whatsapp://send?text=Hello%20World!">Hello, world!</a>`

or

`<a href="https://web.whatsapp.com/send?text=Hello%20World!">Hello, World!</a>`

now If I want to send a Image attachment , how can do that?

Answer (score 3):

U can't. The closest to it would be to send a link in the message that has a image preview, but that's not that usefull. I'm guessing this wouldn't even be possible to add in whatsapp because to access a user file like an image I believe this has to be done with a direct user interaction (like manually selecting the image), but not by clicking a link, just by doing that whatsapp can't get the image from user storage.

Answer (score 0):

Use WhatsApp Business API. You must create an app on Facebook developer panel (https://developers.facebook.com) and add WhatsApp as a product. Then configure api settings and add WhatsApp api web hooks in order to receive replies etc. Configurations on your app or website will depend on what kind of messages(e.g images, audio) you want to send to ur customers.

Answer (score -1):

I guess it would be like this if you are trying to create an image which acts like a link

```html
<a href="https://web.whatsapp.com/send?text=Hello%20World!"><img src="myCoolImage.png" width="500" height="500"></a>
```

Comment: Sorry, I want to send the image to whatsapp as a attachment, not to send  text by clicking on the image.

Comment: But why are you using html to do that?

Comment: any alternate way? e.g.: javascript or php